# Who would touch the ground of a see saw first?

Tags: gravity, torque

Imagine 2 perfectly balanced sea saws.
A heavy person sits on one side of the seasaw.
A light person sits on one side of the other seasaw.
If they both saw down at the same time, which seasaw would touch the ground first?

Answer (score 2):

The seesaw itself has a moment of inertia and it could be ignored for a very heavy person, so the downward acceleration would be nearly $g$.

However for the light person the downward acceleration, and angular acceleration is less.

from $$T=I\alpha$$

(torque is moment of inertia times angular acceleration)

The torque from the light person's weight would cause only a small angular acceleration, so the heavier person would reach the ground first.

Answer (score 0):

The seesaw upon which the heavier person sat will be the first to touch the ground.

A good way to approach questions like this one is to consider extreme cases. Suppose the heavier person weighed 100 tons and the lighter person weighed a microgram- would you have any doubt about which of them would hit the ground first?